# Stripes, GAE: How to implement other methods handling (POST)

Tags: json, google-app-engine, methods, http-post, stripes

Do not know why this (appended method from SomeActionBean.java) does not work on Google app engine? Localy everything runs perfect. Any idea where to look for solution?

```
 /**
 * @return Page to display, filled with correct data
 */
@DefaultHandler
public Resolution welcome() {
    Resolution fd = new ForwardResolution(VIEW);
    HttpServletRequest request = this.ctx.getRequest();
    if(request.getMethod() == "POST") { 
        String content = getRequestContent(request);
        updateData(content);
    }else if (request.getMethod() == "GET"){
        String ct = request.getContentType();
        if(("application/json").equals(ct))
            try {
                getNotesJson(); //fill returnJson global variable
                fd = new JSONResolution(returnJson);
                //TODO Spread to other entities
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return fd;
}
```

Comment: What’s the error you get? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Just figured it out. Its the problem in if and == compare. Kdeveloper, thanks for comment, if you write answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) compares are wrong:

```
request.getMethod() == "POST"
```

Java Strings are not primitives thus they should be compared by *equals* method:

```
"POST".equals(request.getMethod())
```